# How to delete from a table in a performant way

Tags: postgresql, performance, locking

I need to delete some rows with a ROW_NUMBER. As Postgres doesn't support delete on subquery, I need to do:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY col1, col2 ORDER BY col3 DESC, col4 DESC) AS rank_id FROM {working_table}
)
    DELETE FROM {working_table} AS s
    USING cte AS t
    WHERE 
        s.col1 = t.col1
        AND s.col2= t.col2
        AND s.col3 = t.col3
        AND …
        AND rank_id > 3 
        AND s.time <= …
```

which is, I have to do a self-join with all PK cols. The perf is very bad when it is a big table. I'm thinking to insert another table with only SELECT, so I don't have to self-join. And then drop original table and rename the new table. The original table will keep getting new rows. I need to make sure when I do this, now rows will lose. What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Could you elaborate on that claim that PostgreSQL does not support delete on subquery? It works for me.

Comment: For example, I need to delete rows whose id after row_number is bigger than 1. I cannot do:`
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY a ORDER BY b) AS id FROM tbl
)
delete from cte where id >1`. I have to join back the base table.